# Convert a vector grid created with sf::st_make_grid into a raster stack

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf, terra, r-stars

I have a vector grid created with `sf::st_make_grid()` with several columns of
values. I would like to convert it to a raster stack, with each column of values becoming
a layer of the raster stack.

I provide an example below which is close to what I want to achieve.
I have 2 questions problems :

1. is it a good way to approach that problem? Isn't it a more straightforward way to
   convert what is basically a vectorial grid into pixels for a raster?
2. when I plot the vector grid and the raster on top of each other, the grid cells
   are not aligned with the pixels of the raster (see last line using mapview.) I would expect that at least their centroid would be aligned.
   So, I guess I am doing something wrong.

```r
library(sf)
library(terra)

my_cellsize <- 50000

# Load the 'nc' shapefile from the sf package
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")) |> 
    st_transform(crs = 3359) # projection in meters

# Create a grid within the extent of the 'nc' dataset
my_grid <-  st_make_grid(nc, cellsize = my_cellsize)
my_grid <- st_sf(GridID = 1:length(my_grid), my_grid)
my_grid <- my_grid[nc,]

# add some random values
my_grid$value1 <- rnorm(nrow(my_grid))
my_grid$value2 <- rnorm(nrow(my_grid))
my_grid$value3 <- rnorm(nrow(my_grid))

# convert the vector grid into a raster stack
template = rast(vect(my_grid), res = my_cellsize)
value1_raster <- rasterize(vect(my_grid), template, field = "value1")
value2_raster <- rasterize(vect(my_grid), template, field = "value2")
value3_raster <- rasterize(vect(my_grid), template, field = "value3")
stacked_raster <- c(value1_raster, value2_raster, value3_raster)


# interactivbe map showing that the 2 set of grid cells do not overlap correctly
library(mapview)
mapview(stars::st_as_stars(value1_raster)) + mapview(my_grid)
```

Here is a screenshot of the leaflet map showing the misalignment between the vector grid and raster pixels

[image]

I also tried to start from the xy coordinates of the centroids of the cells. But if I understand well, this would work only if I had values on a square grid. Here the cells that are outside the area of interest are considered as missing values and trigger an error message (missing values not allowed)

```r
data.frame(
    my_grid |> st_centroid() |> st_coordinates(),
    my_grid[,c("value1", "value2", "value3"), drop = TRUE]
    ) |> 
    rast(type = "xyz", extent= ext(my_grid), crs = "EPSG:3359")
```

I also tried with `{stars}` with no more success :

```r
template = st_as_stars(st_bbox(my_grid), dx = my_cellsize, dy= my_cellsize, values = NA_real_)
value1_raster = st_rasterize(my_grid, template)
mapview(stars::st_as_stars(value1_raster)) + mapview(my_grid)
```

Comment: I'm unable to explain the behavior, but I noticed that the distortion is sensitive to initial EPSG. If you `st_transform()` the `nc` object to EPSG `32617` instead of `3359` at the beginning, there is less distortion. Maybe this helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no misalignment in the data. You can see that with

```
plot(value1_raster)
lines(my_grid)
```

You see misalignment because you use "mapview"

```
mapview((value1_raster)) + mapview(my_grid)
```

This is because mapview first transforms the data to the coordinate reference system of its base maps. After transformation, the polygon data is no longer a regular grid. But the raster data is transformed to a new regular grid, so the two sources are now misaligned. To avoid that you could transform `nc` to the crs that mapview uses. For example:

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(mapview)

my_cellsize <- 50000
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")) |> 
    st_transform(crs = "+proj=webmerc +datum=WGS84") 
my_grid <-  st_make_grid(nc, cellsize = my_cellsize)
my_grid <- st_sf(GridID = 1:length(my_grid), my_grid)
my_grid <- my_grid[nc,]
my_grid$value1 <- rnorm(nrow(my_grid))
template = rast(vect(my_grid), res = my_cellsize)
value1_raster <- rasterize(vect(my_grid), template, field = "value1")

mapview(value1_raster) + mapview(as.lines(vect(my_grid)))
```

Also, if your goal is to make a raster, then it seems overly complicated and inefficient to first make polygons and rasterize these. You could do something along these lines instead:

```
library(terra)
nc <- vect(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")) |> 
    project(y = "EPSG:3359") 

r <- rast(nc, res=50000)
r$value1 <- rnorm(ncell(r))
r$value2 <- rnorm(ncell(r))
r$value3 <- rnorm(ncell(r))
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Much clearer for me now. What is still strange is that stars rasters can be curvilinear, but the mapview representation seems incorrect. For example, this provides a correct plot of a curvilinear raster in the Mercator transformation 
`stars::st_as_stars(value1_raster) |> 
    st_transform(crs = "+proj=webmerc +datum=WGS84") |> 
    plot(reset = FALSE)
my_grid |> st_transform(crs = "+proj=webmerc +datum=WGS84") |> st_geometry() |> 
    plot(add = TRUE, reset = FALSE, border = "red", lwd = 2, color = NA)`. I will post a comment on github

Comment: Concerning the use of polygons that are then ratserized : my aim is to compute for each grid cell various characteristics from several other vector layers (eg total areas of various land cover polygons, total length of some linear vectors,...), then convert that to a raster stack, then make focal computations on the cells (with a gaussian kernel probably). Not certain that this is the best approach but it was the only path I could see. If there is a better path, I'm all ears :-)

Comment: Issue posted on mapview's github : https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/461